# -ms-transform for IE9 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

How do you set the property of a Div for "-ms-transform" in JavaScript?

I want to rotate a DIV like follows:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
```

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.msTransform = 'rotate(30deg)';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
element.style['transform'] = 'rotate(30deg)';

element.style['msTransform'] = 'rotate(30deg)'; // IE
element.style['MozTransform'] = 'rotate(30deg)'; // Firefox
element.style['WebkitTransform'] = 'rotate(30deg)'; // Chrome
element.style['OTransform'] = 'rotate(30deg)'; // Opera
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mgWCm/